# Tail with case statement is not working properly

Tags: linux, shell-script, grep, pipe, tail

I want to monitor the logs continuously and echo the output if keyword appears then continues the monitoring!!

My question is how to perform the below operation

tail the logs if keyword[down] matches then echo Else continue monitoring i tried this

```
tail -F /data/log/test.log |
egrep -io 'got signal 15 | now exiting' |
while read -r line ; 
do
    case "$line" in
        "got signal 15")
            echo "hi"
            ;;
        "now exiting")
            echo "hi2"
            ;;
        *)
    esac
done
```

But above is not working properly with `tail` statement as the same script works properly if i use `cat` or `less`.

If i use `tail -F` script works till `read -r` line and hangs. But if i use `cat`, i could get the output.

when i try to debug test.sh getting below error

```
sh -x test.sh 
+tail -F /data/log/test.log 
+ egrep -io 'got signal 15|now exiting' +
+ read line
```

and it hangs in the loop
Please suggest what might be the problem here ?